# Not sure how to align my flex items individually along the main axis

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So, I am trying to use flexbox to create a navbar, and basically I want my logo centred and my navbar toggler to the left of the screen.
However, if I give the flex container the justify-content property with the value of center it would just center both my logo as well as my navbar toggler.

I wanted to know whether there is something similar to align-self property but for the main axis?
So I can set my logo to center and my navbar toggler to the left of my screen?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<header class="main-navbar">
      <div class="nav-toggler">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="brand">
        <a class="logo-link" href="#">
          <img src="imgs/logo/logo-lightgrey.png" alt="logo-brand-image">
        </a>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Here is my css code:

```
.main-navbar {
  position:fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 3.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.nav-toggler {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-toggler span {
  width: 1.3rem;
  height: 0.17rem;
  background: white;
  display: block;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Push both child elements with **margin-right: auto**

```css
.main-navbar {
  position:fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 3.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: #000;
}

.nav-toggler {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-toggler span {
  width: 1.3rem;
  height: 0.17rem;
  background: white;
  display: block;
}

/**/
.nav-toggler,
.brand {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-navbar">
      <div class="nav-toggler">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="brand">
        <a class="logo-link" href="#">
          <img src="https://www.placehold.it/100x50" alt="logo-brand-image">
        </a>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Although, your solution somewhat centers the logo, but it's not perfectly centered. I wanted the logo to be exactly in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a pure flex solution for this. You may need to try adding `position: absolute` to `.nav-toggler` instead. This will remove the toggler from the overall flow and allow the logo to sit in the centre unaffected.

```css
.main-navbar {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 3.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: black;
}

.nav-toggler {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav-toggler span {
  width: 1.3rem;
  height: 0.17rem;
  background: white;
  display: block;
}

.brand img {
  display: block; /* not necessary, just added to vertically align image for demo */
}
```

```html
<header class="main-navbar">
  <div class="nav-toggler">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="brand">
    <a class="logo-link" href="#">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/30/animals" alt="logo-brand-image">
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
```